# How to change the index in a list of lists

Tags: python

I would like to change the way a list of lists in indexed.

Suppose my initial list is two lists of one list and two lists of three elements. For example:

```
L = [[[1, 2, 3]], [[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]]
```

Then let say I want to take '4' in L, I must do

```
L[1][0][0].
```

Now I'd like to create a new list such that the last indexing become the first one

```
Lnew = [[[1], [4, 7]], [[2], [5, 8]], [[3], [6, 9]]]
```

And then for taking '4' I have to do:

```
Lnew[0][1][0]
```

In a more general case, I'd like to create the list Lnew defined by:

```
Lnew[i][k][l] = L[k][l][i]
```

Is there a way to do this kind of permutation of the index without doing the following loops:

```
Lnew = []
for i in range(len(Payment_dates)):
    L1 = []
    for k in range(N+1):
        L2 = []
        for l in range(k+1):
            L2.append(L[k][l][i])
        L1.append(L2)
    Lnew.append(L1)
```

Which is not very optimal in term of complexity.

Thanks

Comment: So your question is this one right? `Now I'd like to create a new list such that the last indexing become the first one`

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want this?

Comment: are you trying to parse any csv file with 3 columns?
Better way to use the dict.

Comment: Can you use numpy?

Comment: I am manipulating binary trees and so the structure of Lnew is better but my inputs are always as L.

Comment: I can use numpy

Comment: But how is numpy useful for this? The sublists in the output have different lengths

Answer (score 0):

What you'd like to achieve, presupposes that all sublists have the same length.

If they have differing lengths, you may wish to append zeros to all sublists until they have the length of the longest sublist or (which is easier) until infinity.

The same behaviour can be achieved by using a function to access the elements of the list. You can call this function during runtime every time you need an element of the list:

```
def getElement(myList, i, k, l):
    if k < myList.length and l < myList[k].length and i < myList[k][l].length:
        return myList[k][l][i]
    else: 
        return None # or zero, or whatever you prefer
```

Depending on your code structure, you might not need this as a function and you can just put the conditions inside of your code.

You can also nest the if-conditions and throw different errors or return different values depending on what level the element does not exist.

If we neglect the time complexity of outputting a multidimensional list's element, this approach should decrease your time complexity from O(n^3) to O(1).